# how can i query google places for country specific cuisine?

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-places-api

i am trying to accomplish country specific Cuisine places, means like mexican food, spanish food, Thai food, indian food, via google places API on an iPhone app. 
How can i do that?? As i see supported types, there is only food, restaurant, etc in it. besides whenever i use this query..

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&type=restaurant&query=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

i am getting few results only, whenever i try to add more types like food|restaurant|establishment like below query my app crashes.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&type=food|restaurant|establishment&query=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

As i told my app crashes with this error may be i am doing something wrong with url.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13be022 0x200fcd6 0x1366a48 0x13669b9 0xbadfad 0x2dd2 0x13bfe42 0xaa09df 0x139294f 0x12f5b43 0x12f5424
>   0x12f4d84 0x12f4c9b 0x15d47d8 0x15d488a 0x17a626 0x236d 0x22d5)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Please can someone guide me with this?? i hope i cleared all my points.

Thanks & regards,
Malhaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use the Places API Textsearch as you are using the `query` parameter. If this is correct make sure you are hitting the correct backend:

> maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/**textsearch**/json

Also make sure you are using the correct parameter to specify types:

> **types**=food|restaurant|establishment

I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation) thoroughly and and performing a few [test html requests](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?sensor=true&keyword=peets&location=37.3943,-122.151&radius=50000&types=food|restaurant|establishment&key=YOUR_API_KEY) through your browser to make sure you have the right request before plugging it into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is almost 7 months old, and I'm sure you've either solved it or given up on it by now, I have just had the same issue and it took some resolving. I thought I'd put the answer here to help anyone else with a similar error.

The problem I found was to do with the URL encoding not liking the `|` character.

The way around it I found was to:

```
// Create an NSString with the URL which includes the '|' characters.
NSString * urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.189781,-114.488907&radius=6918&types=food|bar&keyword=&sensor=true&key=YOUR KEY HERE";

// Encode the URL
NSString* encodedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Covert to a NSURL
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
```

And then use the `googleRequestURL` as the URL.

Hopefully that will solve it for you!